# Pass class name to method

Tags: c#, json, oop, windows-runtime, windows-phone

I am writing a Windows Phone 8.1 App (WINRT). I have to call **HTTPHandlerMethod** method accepting **three parameters**. I pass **Server API address as string**, **JsonString to be send to server as string**, and also I need to **send class name** to HTTPHandlerMethod also as third parameter. How to send **class name**? I actually need to use class name inside this method in JSON DeSerializing:

> JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSonData_Recieved,CLASS NAME HERE);

```
 public async void HTTPHandlerMethod(string AddressPath,
    string JSonData_ToSend, **WHAT THIRD PARAMETER TO WRITE HERE??**)
 {
     Object resObject = null;
     HttpBaseProtocolFilter HttpBaseProtocolFilterObject = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
     HttpClient HttpClientObject = new HttpClient(HttpBaseProtocolFilterObject);

     string CompleteAddress = singletonInstance.APIServer + AddressPath;
     Uri UriObject = new Uri(CompleteAddress);
     HttpRequestMessage HttpRequestMessageObject = 
        new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, UriObject);

     HttpRequestMessageObject.Content = new HttpStringContent(JSonData_ToSend,
           Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "application/json");

     try
     {
       HttpResponseMessage HttpResponseMessageObject = 
              await HttpClientObject.SendRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessageObject,
                   HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);

       if (HttpResponseMessageObject.IsSuccessStatusCode)  //If 2xx success is recieved
       {
          string JSonData_Recieved = 
             await HttpResponseMessageObject.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         resObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSonData_Recieved,resType);
        }
     }
     catch  { }
   }
 }
```

What modifications should I do to this **HTTPHandlerMethod** method? and how to call it then?

Comment: Context is everything. _What_ class name do you want to pass? What relationship does the caller have to the class in question? Why can't you just hard-code the name as a literal? Could you make the method a generic class and use the type parameter _instead of_ passing a class name? Please include [a _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates precisely and clearly what you're asking.

Comment: What are you going to do with the class name? I guess you need a generic type parameter.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Looks like OP wants to call [JsonConvert.DeserializeObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm) that takes `Type` as second parameter... Not really clear what exactly is causing problem for OP so...

Answer (score 0):

```
 public async void HTTPHandlerMethod(string AddressPath,
    string JSonData_ToSend, Type classname)
 {

}
```